# unique key on varchar is ignored for maria db

Tags: mariadb, where

I have the following table:

```
| s3entry | CREATE TABLE `s3entry` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `S3KEY` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FETCHESSINCELASTS3FETCH` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inS3Store` tinyint(4) DEFAULT 0,
  `inLocalCache` tinyint(4) DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `s3key` (`S3KEY`) USING HASH,
  KEY `inS3Store_inLocalCache_lastcachefetch` (`inS3Store`,`inLocalCache`,`LASTCACHEFETCH`),
  KEY `inLocalCache_lastfetch` (`inLocalCache`,`LASTCACHEFETCH`),
  KEY `cache_size` (`inLocalCache`,`inS3Store`,`size`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5847320 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
```

The table has some 5 million records.
When I run the following query it ignores the s3key index:

```
explain SELECT * FROM s3entry force index (s3key) WHERE s3key  = 'some long text of about 400 bytes that exactly matches an s3key in the db';
+------+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+------+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | s3entry | ALL  | s3key         | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 5570486 | Using where |
+------+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Given the exact match and the simple where clause I'm expecting mariadb to use the key.

I've also tried explicitly passing the collation in the query:

```
MariaDB [op]> explain SELECT * FROM s3entry WHERE s3key collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci  = 'some long text of about 400 bytes that exactly matches an s3key in the db';

+------+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+------+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | s3entry | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 5763585 | Using where |
+------+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

I can solve the problem by adding an index to the table on the same key, but this seems unnecessary:

```
 s3entry | CREATE TABLE `s3entry` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CREATEDAT` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `guid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `LASTS3FETCH` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `size` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LASTCACHEFETCH` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `S3KEY` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FETCHESSINCELASTS3FETCH` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inS3Store` tinyint(4) DEFAULT 0,
  `inLocalCache` tinyint(4) DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `s3key` (`S3KEY`) USING HASH,
  KEY `inS3Store_inLocalCache_lastcachefetch` (`inS3Store`,`inLocalCache`,`LASTCACHEFETCH`),
  KEY `inLocalCache_lastfetch` (`inLocalCache`,`LASTCACHEFETCH`),
  KEY `cache_size` (`inLocalCache`,`inS3Store`,`size`),
  KEY `s3key2` (`S3KEY`(768))
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5856082 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci |



explain SELECT * FROM s3entry WHERE s3key = 'some long text of about 400 bytes that exactly matches an s3key in the db';
+------+-------------+---------+------+---------------------+--------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys       | key    | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+---------+------+---------------------+--------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | s3entry | ref  | s3key,s3key2 | s3key2 | 3075    | const | 1    | Using where |
+------+-------------+---------+------+---------------------+--------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

I don't understand why the hash won't work.

Comment: Which version of MariaDB?

Comment: @RickJames 1:10.11.6+maria~ubu2204
apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends mariadb-server="$MARIADB_VERSION" mariadb-backup socat

Comment: See also https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-27653

Comment: 1.10.11.6 does not sound like a valid version.

Comment: @RickJames that is 1: not 1.  This is from the official dockerhub maria db image. I have my own copy but with only minor changes (group ids)  I interpret this as 10.11.6.
The noted bug is also rather confusing . Its starts of with a demo of a string but then responders go on to note:  but only for timestamp it has actually caused a bug.  So I'm a litle confused how it applies.

Comment: The developers responded in that bug report.

Comment: If collations are not an issue, consider changing to `BINARY(1024)`.

Comment: Think I found it - this issue [MDEV-31072](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-31072)

Comment: From the last comment in https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-27653 "it's a complain that the optimizer doesn't use an index to optimize the query. This is correct, optimizer doesn't, this is not implemented (yet). But the UNIQUE isn't ignored, the uniqueness constraint holds, it applies on inserts and updates. But the optimizer cannot use it for SELECT."

Comment: @VladislavVaintroub if you want to change your comment to an answer I will mark it as correct. Thanks for you assistance !